# X-Path + RegEx matching pattern

Tags: regex, xpath, query-string

Given the following,

```
<Line>
    <Supplier>Fuel Surcharge - 36</Supplier>
    <Supplier>Fuel Surcharge - 35</Supplier>
    <Supplier>46081 46150 46250 46280 46286</Supplier>
    <Supplier>Fuel Surcharge - 35451</Supplier>
    <Supplier>46081</Supplier>
</Line>
```

The idea here is to return "true" when the node carries a number of 5 digits with iteration.

This is what I have done so far,

```
matches(./Supplier, "[^(\d{5}\s*)+]");
```

The regex here is to extract the value that has 5 digits with or without space regardless of the iteration.

The results I am getting is all true. Means its not right somewhere. Can you assist me with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your expression:

- No semicolon in the end of an XPath expression (syntax error).
- Your regex is messed up, it matches everything that does not contain anything out of the character class parentheses, digits, curly brackets, the digit 5, spaces, and the star and plus character.
- `fn:matches(xs:string?, xs:string)` requires two strings as parameters, you're passing a sequence of strings for the first one.

To call a function *for each node in an axis step*, add it as another one (XPath 2.0 and above only). You can use the dot `.` (context) in the arguments.

Try something like

```
./Supplier/matches(., "^(\d{5}\s*)+$")
```

which will yield true for the third and fifth row. If it only must *contain* (and not fully constructed from) the repeating pattern of fife-digit-numbers and spaces, remove the `^` and `$` from the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: `matches(./Supplier, '(.*)((\d{5}(\s*))+)(.*)')`